# Node.js insert query not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm trying to get a insert query to work because i've made a quiz in Javascript and i want the result to be uploaded on a database. this is my code (including the quiz):

```
<script>    
(function() { //the questions
var questions = [{
question: "What year was starcraft released?",
choices: [1990, 1992, 1994, 1996, 1998],
correctAnswer: 4
}, {
question: "What was the first Starcraft expension called?",
choices: ["Brood War", "War of the Worlds", "Wings of Liberty", "Zerg rush", 
"Legacy of the Void"],
correctAnswer: 0
}, {
question: "When was Warcraft: Orcs & Humans released?",
choices: [1990, 1992, 1994, 1996, 1998],
correctAnswer: 2
}, {
question: "When was Blizzard founded?",
choices: [1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994],
correctAnswer: 1
}, {
question: "What is Blizzard´s latest new game?",
choices: ["Overwatch", "Heroes of the Storm", "Warcraft 3", "Starcraft 2: 
Wings of Liberty", "Heartstone"],
correctAnswer: 0
}, {
question: "What was Blizzards first game?",
choices: ["RPM Racing", "The lost Vikings", "Starcraft", "Warcraft: Orcs & 
Humans", "Heartstone"],
correctAnswer: 0
               }];

var questionCounter = 0; //Tracks question number
var selections = []; //Array containing user choices
var quiz = $('#quiz'); //Quiz div object

// Display initial question
displayNext();

// Click handler for the 'next' button
$('#next').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

// Suspend click listener during fade animation
if(quiz.is(':animated')) {        
  return false;
}
choose();

// If no user selection, progress is stopped
if (isNaN(selections[questionCounter])) {
  alert('please choose an answer');
} else {
  questionCounter++;
  displayNext();
}
});

// Click handler for the 'prev' button
$('#prev').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

if(quiz.is(':animated')) {
  return false;
}
choose();
questionCounter--;
displayNext();
});

// Click handler for the 'Start Over' button
$('#start').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

if(quiz.is(':animated')) {
  return false;
}
questionCounter = 0;
selections = [];
displayNext();
$('#start').hide();
});

// Animates buttons on hover
$('.button').on('mouseenter', function () {
$(this).addClass('active');
});
$('.button').on('mouseleave', function () {
$(this).removeClass('active');
});

// Creates and returns the div that contains the questions and 
// the answer selections
function createQuestionElement(index) {
var qElement = $('<div>', {
  id: 'question'
});

var header = $('<h2>Question ' + (index + 1) + ':</h2>');
qElement.append(header);

var question = $('<p>').append(questions[index].question);
qElement.append(question);

var radioButtons = createRadios(index);
qElement.append(radioButtons);

return qElement;
}

// Creates a list of the answer choices as radio inputs
function createRadios(index) {
var radioList = $('<ul>');
var item;
var input = '';
for (var i = 0; i < questions[index].choices.length; i++) {
  item = $('<li>');
  input = '<input type="radio" name="answer" value=' + i + ' />';
  input += questions[index].choices[i];
  item.append(input);
  radioList.append(item);
}
return radioList;
}

// Reads the user selection and pushes the value to an array
function choose() {
selections[questionCounter] = +$('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();
}

// Displays next requested element
function displayNext() {
quiz.fadeOut(function() {
  $('#question').remove();

  if(questionCounter < questions.length){
    var nextQuestion = createQuestionElement(questionCounter);
    quiz.append(nextQuestion).fadeIn();
    if (!(isNaN(selections[questionCounter]))) {
      $('input[value='+selections[questionCounter]+']').prop('checked', 
    true);
    }

    // Controls display of 'prev' button
    if(questionCounter === 1){
      $('#prev').show();
    } else if(questionCounter === 0){

      $('#prev').hide();
      $('#next').show();
    }
    }else {
    var scoreElem = displayScore();
    quiz.append(scoreElem).fadeIn();
    $('#next').hide();
    $('#prev').hide();
    $('#start').show();
  }
  });
  }

  // Computes score and returns a paragraph element to be displayed
  function displayScore() {
  var score = $('<p>',{id: 'question'});

  var numCorrect = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
   if (selections[i] === questions[i].correctAnswer) {
    numCorrect++;
  }
  }

  score.append('You got ' + numCorrect + ' questions out of ' +
             questions.length + ' right! That is ' + 
  numCorrect/questions.length * 100 + "% !");
  return score;
  }
  }

  )();

     var mysql = require('mysql');

  var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "******",
  password: "****,
  database: "*******"
  });

  con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sql = "INSERT INTO scores (score, quiz, gebruikersnaam) VALUES (100, 
  1, 'jeroen')";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("1 record inserted");
  });
  });
```

if you can please help me get this working i would be really happy thx in advance 
p.s. the quiz is working the results just wont get uploaded to the database

Comment: You're running this in a browser?

Comment: i'm running it in google chrome yea

Comment: Yeah you can't do that. Node.js is server-side. You need to find a way of creating the server, then sending your results to it to store in the database.

Comment: which type of error rise in your code

Comment: no error rises it works fine only the results won't get stored in the database

Comment: They won't get stored in the database because it can't connect to the database. There is no TCP stack in the browser to be able to communicate with a MySQL server.

Comment: No error, not even a little _Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined_ ?